# Union which mutate array in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a function in lodash which makes a union of two arrays by modifying the first one? Union should add the element only if there are no duplicates.

Something along the lines of

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]; _.mergeArrays(a, [6,7]); 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: Nope. But why would you need this ?

Comment: You can just use `Array.concat()` for this without lodash. `arr = [1, 2, 3].concat([4, 5]) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Isn't it what array's `.splice` already does, too?

Comment: Note that `concat` does not modify the original list as was requested.  But `splice` does.

Comment: Concat and splice add the element even if it already exists. Union implies it should be unique in the array. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with "vanilla" JavaScript. It requires ES5 (2009) only, which is implemented by all the major web browsers.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var anotherArray = [6,7];
anotherArray.forEach(function(val) {
  if (array.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    array.push(val);
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for lodash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread element, `Set` which does not allow duplicate entries

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var add = [6, 7, 3, 5];
a = [...new Set([...a, ...add])];
console.log(a);
```

Comment: It's just that you need ES6 for that.

Comment: @MarkusIvancsics Not sure what you mean? Is expected result an array which does not contain duplicate elements?

Comment: Union means values that are presented in array1 or array2. If you use this code, you will add it twice if it was in ```a``` and ```add``` too.
(e.g ```var a = [1,2,3]; var add = [2,3]``` => [1,2,3,2,3])